# Macro to assign default values, avoid collision of variable names

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Here's a small macro I want to call at the start of my macro functions.

It is the equivalent of `%if not %length(&x) %then %let x = &val`.

I want to use it as it's more readable and will help me to parse my code to build documentation (Which I need to do with regex as I can't install external softwares).

```
%macro def
/*---------------------
Assign default value
---------------------*/
(_x_data_x_  /* variable name (to be passed raw without &) */
,value       /* default value */
);
%if not %length(&&&_x_data_x_) %then %let &_x_data_x_ = &value;
%mend;
```

Here's how it works:

```
%macro test(a,b);
  %def(b,&a)
  %put "&b";
%mend;

%test(%str(,)); /* prints "," */
```

I chose the unusual parameter name `_x_data_x_` because the macro fails when it's fed a value equal to the parameter's name (i.e. if my `b` parameter was named `_x_data_x_`).

Can I make it really safe, apart from choosing obscure names ?

Comment: Curious why you want to use this approach, rather that just make b a keyword parameter and give it a default value when you define the macro, ie `%macro test(a,b=&a)` ?

Comment: I use it as much as possible, but in some cases I really don't want a keyword parameter. It's the main reason. I was also curious about the general way to apply side effects of the kind as I have some different applications in mind.

Comment: As for the **equivalent of**, should the %let instead be stated as `%if not %length(&x) %then %let &x = &val;` ?  (i.e. %let x= versus %let &x=).  If not, why test the length of &x ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow you. I'm using this code at the beginning of a function, if argument x was not provided it's empty and `&x` has no length, then I give it a default value with `%let x`, not `%let &x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the correct approach.

You could make the macro more robust by adding checks:

```
 %* Prevent self reference because 
 %* assignment will not bubble to containing scope;

 %if %upcase(%superq(x_data_x)) eq X_DATA_X %then %do;
   %put ERROR: x_data_x=%superq(x_data_x) is not allowed;
   %abort cancel;
 %end;

 %* Prevent reference to non-existent because
 %* assignment will automatically localize 
 %* and not bubble to containing scope;

 %if not %symexist (%superq(x_data_x)) %then %do;
   %put ERROR: x_data_x=%superq(x_data_x) is invalid;
   %put ERROR: %superq(x_data_x) does not exist in callee scope;
   %abort cancel;
 %end;
```